# Cerrar frame al abrir otro?

Tags: java

Probe con dispose y setVisible pero en primer lugar, ocultan, no cierran, y a parte, no me estarian funcionando. Necesitaria cerrarla por completo, no solo ocultarla.

Las ventanas que seabren son las de administrador y/u operador, necesitaria cerrar la ventana desde la que estoy cuando abre alguna de esas dos:.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Siempre para pasar de un formulario a otro he utilizado:

```
FormularioPrincipal frm = new FormularioPrincipal();
frm.setVisible(true);
this.dispose();
```

Y jamás me ha dado problema, al usuario jamás le volverá a aparecer el formulario y el proceso tampoco queda ejecutandose

Comment: No, ya le probé y no funciona. Va todo bien hasta que le doy en el boton "ingresar"  y no se ciera el login. Sigue abierto junto con el frame que abrí desde ahí.

Comment: Yo lo he utilizado desde siempre y te aseguro que funciona 100%, por lo que veo en las capturas de tu codigo en ningun momentos utilizas el `this.dispose`, debe ir en la línea siguiente de los `setVisible(true);` al abrir el form o del admin o del operador